# Filter v-for array to return specific IDs only -Vue.js

Tags: javascript, loops, vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

I am trying to loop through an array with v-for but I need to list specific IDs only.
I've tried this code so far

```
<template>
    <div v-for="item in Items" v-if="item.id === '1,4,9,44,98'" :item="item" :key="item.id">{{ item.name }}</div>
</template>

<page-query>
  query {
    items {
       id
       name
    }
  }
</page-query>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
          items: Array,
        }
        computed: {
          Items() {
            return this.items
          },
        }
    }
</script>
```

How can I list specific IDs using v-for and v-if in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, you can do the filtering in the computed section where you are returning the items props:

```
 computed: {
          Items() {
            return this.items.filter((item,index)=>{return index>0 && index<5})
          }
        }
```

then what you will have as items is the original filtered items

Comment: Thank you! How can I do this for specific indexes? this currently filters <5.

Comment: @AliSeivani well I answered based on your example in the question, but there should be a pattern  IDK if 5 here is the length of your `items` array then you can filter them based on this condition: ` index>0 && index<this.items.length`

Comment: In my case I get a list of items from API example: {1,4,9,44,98} then I have to filter the list according these IDs. so slicing is not really solution for me.

Comment: @AliSeivani  okay, I didn't know this before, if you are getting a list of ids I think our friend's solution up there is the exact match for your request: `return this.items.filter((item,index)=>{return [1,4,9,44,98].includes(index) })`

Comment: This works. Really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your `Items` property should filter that ids like :

```
Items() {
            return this.items.filter(item=>[1,2,3,4].includes(item.id))
          },
```

template :

```
 <div v-for="item in Items"  :item="item" :key="item.id">{{ item.name }}</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but it does not work. I thought of using a computed property to filter the list but your example didn't return any result!

Comment: if `this.items` returns data so `this.items.filter...` should also return

Comment: this.items does return but after adding filter it does not work.

Comment: Try out `this.items.filter(item=>[1,2,3,4].some(id=>id==item.id))`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. @blackSheep solution in the comment worked just fine.

Comment: what about `return this.items.filter((item,i)=>[1,2,3,4].includes(i))`